# Navegación entre ventanas con tkinter

Tags: python

Hola comunidad de stackoverflow.

Necesito ayuda con un problema, estoy empezando en python y quisiera practicar con tkinter, sé crear ventanas y botones, pero quisiera crear un botón que me deje navegar entre varias ventanas.
¿Eso es posible? Si es asi, ¿me podrían decir el método para hacerlo?

```
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("720x480")


boton1 = Button(ventana, text="Anterior Pagina").place(x=0,y=450)

boton2 = Button(ventana, text="Siguiente Pagina").place(x=605,y=450)

boton3 = Button(ventana, text="Salir", command=ventana.destroy).place(x=0,y=0)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Añade el código que tienes hasta ahora, así es posible guiarte :)

Comment: en si ese es un código sencillo, lo que quisiera saber es si en los botones 1 y 2 se pueden agregar alguna función, con la cual si aprieto el botón 2 me abra una nueva venta y en el botón 1 me regrese a la venta anterior

Answer (score -1):

Encontré este código, entiendo la mayoría de lo que esta ahí, si lo entiendes genial!

Si tienes alguna duda sobre el código, puedes dejarla y te ayudo en lo que pueda xD, de todas maneras puedes usarlo para hacerte una idea de como hacer las interacciones.

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
#import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
#import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: gracias por responder a mi duda Jorge, espero poner en practica este código para ver si me sirve.

Answer (score -2):

Mira te comparto este codigo puede ser que te sirva>>>

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("720x480")
    
    def close():
        
        return True
    #boton1 = Button(root, text="Anterior Pagina").place(x=0,y=450)
    
    #boton2 = Button(root, text="Siguiente Pagina").place(x=605,y=450)
    
    #boton3 = Button(root, text="Salir", command=root.destroy).place(x=0,y=0)
    
    # Menu
    mainMenu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu = mainMenu)
    
    # Submenu
        # Home
    home = Menu(mainMenu, tearoff = 0)
    home.add_command(label = "Home")
    
        # Insert
    insert = Menu(root, tearoff = 0)
    insert.add_command(label = "New Employee")
    insert.add_separator()
    insert.add_command(label = "New Car")
    insert.add_separator()
    insert.add_command(label = "New Car use")
    
        # Edit menu
    edit = Menu(mainMenu, tearoff = 0)
    edit.add_command(label = "Edit Employee")
    edit.add_separator()
    edit.add_command(label = "Edit Car")
    
        # Delete menu
    delete = Menu(mainMenu, tearoff = 0)
    delete.add_command(label = "Delete Employee")
    delete.add_separator()
    delete.add_command(label = "Delete Car")
    delete.add_separator()
    delete.add_command(label = "Delete Car use")
    
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label = "Home", menu = home, command = home)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label = "Insert", menu = insert, command = insert)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label = "Edit", menu = edit, command = edit)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label = "Delete", menu = delete, command = delete)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label = "Close", menu = close, command = root.quit)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No se puede considerar respuesta de calidad, explícanos como se resuelve el problema del OP

Comment: Una respuesta sin explicación no es respuesta; es un acto mágico. Pronuncias algunas palabras encantadas, incomprensibles para el resto, y pump!!! problema solucionado. ¿Cual era el problema? No se. ¿Por qué esta es la solución? Tampoco lo se. ¿Que aprenderan otros de esta respuesta? nada.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Gracias por intentar aportar a la causa de responder la pregunta. Sin embargo, piensa que estas respuestas las usan personas ahora y en el futuro; trata de explicar un poco más el porqué tu código resuelve la pregunta, qué hace, cómo lo hace, cómo se usa, etc. Puedes editar tu respuesta todas las veces que desees usando el enlace Editar justo debajo

Comment: Alfabravo tienes razon lo tendre encuenta para la proxima.